# How to prevent HP Photosmart Essential from launching on removal drive insertion

Tags: windows-registry, memory-card, autoplay, hp-photosmart

My in-laws bought an HP computer loaded with HP junk, and it's giving me a headache.

When they insert a camera memory card into their printer, the Auto-Play dialog comes up, but it also launches the HP Photosmart Essential application, which is a piece of trash. It will NOT launch properly just normally from the taskbar, so that makes it pretty useless.

I tried uninstalling it, but then when you insert a memory card, a Microsoft Help window comes up saying how to reinstall HP Photosmart Essential!!

Is there any way to find the registry key (I assume) that allows a program to be launched when a memory card is inserted?

Comment: Are you sure it isn't part of the autorun.inf on the card itself?

Comment: Yes, checked, and multiple cards cause the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

These are instructions when using Windows 7 and concerning the HP PhotoSmart All-in-One Driver Software 13.0 Rel. 2.  If you have another version or another printer series, the instructions may differ.

- Go to the system try in the notification area, right click on "HP Digital Imaging Monitor"
- Move cursor over "Camera Phone Photos"
- Click "Turn off HP Import"

That will prevent HP Photo Essentials from starting if you only have the printer connected one way.

If you are conneccted to the printer multiple ways, such as USB and via your network, you can prevent HP Photo Essentials from starting, but HP Solution Center will still pop-up.